# Measuring inductance and resistance of a coil

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

If you had a resistive coil with an inductance and a resistance, a sinusoidal voltage source with a variable frequency, and a meter that can measure rms voltages and currents, how would you go about determining the inductance and resistance of the coil?

I know that the complex impedance of the coil is $i\omega L + R$, so the current through the coil will be $I = \frac{V}{i\omega L + R}$, but I am not sure what to do from this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\left (\dfrac{V_{\rm rms}}{I_{\rm rms}}\right )^2=L^2\, \omega^2+R^2 = (4\,\pi^2 L^2)\, f^2+R^2$ is of the form of the general equation of a straight line, $y = m\,x +c$, then taking a series of $V_{\rm rms}$ and $I_{\rm rms}$ readings at different frequencies, $f$, and drawing a graph of $\left (\dfrac{V_{\rm rms}}{I_{\rm rms}}\right )^2$ against $f^2$ should give a straight line of gradient $4\,\pi^2 L^2$ and intercept on the $\left (\dfrac{V_{\rm rms}}{I_{\rm rms}}\right )^2$ axis of $R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

With your meter you can measure only the rms of voltage and current,
but not their phases. Therefore from the complex impedance
$$\frac{V}{I}=Z=i\omega L+R$$
you can only measure its absolute value
$$\frac{V_\text{rms}}{I_\text{rms}}=|Z|=\sqrt{(\omega L)^2+R^2}.$$

So with your meter you need to measure $|Z|$ for at least two frequencies (or for  DC and one frequency).
From these $|Z|$ values you can then calculate $R$ and $L$.